# Как проверить нажата ли любая кнопка?

Tags: c

К примеру, на просторах интернета есть такой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

main()
      {
        printf("Приготовившись, нажмите любую клавишу\n");
        while(!kbhit());
        printf("\n Была нажата клавиша (%c)\n", getch());
      }
```

Мне нужно примерно следующее:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main() {
    while (1){
        //некий код
        if ( kbhit() ) {
            printf("Кнопка нажата \n");
        }
        //некий код
    }
}
```

При попытке скомпилировать в gcc на MacOS компилятор выплевывает фразу :

```
fatal error: conio.h: No such file or directory
2 |      #include <conio.h>
  |               ^~~~~~~~~
```

И два вопроса как, возможно исключающие друг друга

1. Есть ли возможность заменить этот кусок кода? И что-бы скомпилировалось без ошибок без использования conio.h?
2. Или! Как (куда?) установить (закинуть в папку с компилятором или как?) этот conio?
3. ну или заменить на какой-нибудь scanf из разряда типа

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int main() {
> char ch;
>         while (1){
>             //некий код
>             if ( scanf("%c", ch) = 'кнопка нажата') {
>                 printf("Кнопка нажата \n");
>             } else { ( scanf("%c", ch) = 'кнопка не нажата') {
>                 printf("Кнопка не нажата \n");
>             }
>             //некий код
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: Поставьте `ncurses` и напишите `kbhit`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4028974/14775762

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что будет конфликт nurses и studio? Пр попытке добавить команды из ncurses консоль начинает всё выводить лесенкой!

Comment: У меня нет опыта, но как я понимаю, сочетать стандартный вывод и ncurses можно, но надо изучить пару трюков.